# questions about transversal surfaces (curves) to a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

The following is an excerpt from *[Dynamical Systems](http://www.math.harvard.edu/library/sternberg/)* by Shlomo Sternberg:

> By a **transversal**, $L$, to the vector field $V$ we mean a surface of codimension
>   one which is nowhere tangent to $V$ . In the plane, this means that $L$ is a curve.
>
> In particular, the vector field, $V$ does not vanish at any point of $L$. If
>   $V (A) \not= 0$, we can always find a transversal to $V$ passing through $A$: *Simply
>   choose a subspace of codimension one of the tangent space at $A$ which does not
>   contain $V (A)$, and then choose a surface tangent to this subspace at $ A$.* At all
>   points sufficiently near to $A$ the vector field $V$ will not be tangent to this surface
>   on account of continuity.

I don't understand the part "If
$V (A) \not= 0$, we can always find a transversal to $V$ passing through $A$: *Simply
choose a subspace of codimension one of the tangent space at $A$ which does not
contain $V (A)$, and then choose a surface tangent to this subspace at $ A$.*" Can any one come up with a picture showing how this is done in ${\Bbb R}^2$ and ${\Bbb R}^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ${\Bbb R}^2$ and ${\Bbb R}^3$ it's very easy, since you don't have to make the distinction between the manifold and its tangent space. Just take $L$ to be the line (in ${\Bbb R}^2$) or the plane (in ${\Bbb R}^3$) which passes through the point $A$ and has $V(A)$ as its normal vector.

Comment: ($V(A)$ doesn't actually have to be orthogonal to the plane/line $L$, just as long as it doesn't point *along* $L$.)